# Can you get a table to auto format numbers to show parentheses on negative figures?

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334154/54029) to my connected question, where I had negatives figures shown in parentheses it was necessary in the answer to add them as pre and post text. My question resulting from this solution now is it possible if I put a negative figure in a table can latex format it to show in parentheses. So in the MWE below instead of typing `{(}50000{)}` I can type -50000 and the output will be (50000).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={,}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Income \& Expenditure Account} 
\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{
  p{7.5cm}
  c
  *2{S[table-format=6.0, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)]}
}  
& \textbf{Note} & {\textbf{2016}} & {\textbf{2015}} \\
\midrule
Income & 1 & 100000 & 102000 \\
\cmidrule{3-4}\\ 
Cost of Sales & 2 & {(}50000{)} & {(}45000{)} \\
\cmidrule{3-4} 
Gross Profit & & 50000 & 57000 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While re-inventing the wheel was fun, I decided to use the `xstring` and `siunitx` packages instead.

The macros `\acount` and `\bcount` are used to format numbers using (positive) for negative terms. `\bcount` will convert integers to decimals.

The second step is to create new column types A and B which automatically expands these macro.  Note the use of `\multicolumn` in the top row to handle text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\acount}[1]% #1 = number
{\IfBeginWith{#1}{-}{\StrBehind{#1}{-}[\temp](\num[group-separator={,}]{\temp}\rlap{)}}%
   {\num[group-separator={,}]{#1}}}

\newcommand{\bcount}[1]% #1 = decimal number
{\IfBeginWith{#1}{-}{\StrBehind{#1}{-}[\temp]%
     (\num[group-separator={,},round-mode=places,round-precision=2,round-integer-to-decimal]{\temp}\rlap{)}}%
   {\num[group-separator={,},round-mode=places,round-precision=2,round-integer-to-decimal]{#1}}}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\collectcell\acount}r<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\collectcell\bcount}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Income \& Expenditure Account} 
\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{p{8.25cm}cAA}  
& \textbf{Note} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{2016}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{2015}} \\ \hline\\ 
Income & 1 & 100000 & 102000 \\ \cline{3-4}\\ 
Cost of Sales & 2 & -50000 & -45000 \\ \cline{3-4} 
Gross Profit & & 50000 & 57000 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section*{Income \& Expenditure Account} 
\begin{table}[htb] 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{p{8.25cm}cBB}  
& \textbf{Note} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{2016}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{2015}} \\ \hline\\ 
Income & 1 & 100000 & 102000 \\ \cline{3-4}\\ 
Cost of Sales & 2 & -50000 & -45000 \\ \cline{3-4} 
Gross Profit & & 50000 & 57000 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Since you've done most of the work here, use the `collcell` package: `\newcolumntype{A}{>{\collectcell\acount}r<{\endcollectcell}}` and remove the `\bgroup` and `\egroup` from your `\account` macro.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Thank you.  I take it the \bgroup ... \egroup was redundant rather than harmful.

Comment: Is there any way to incorporate the thousand separators like in the MWE?

Comment: The second solution is really good. Last request hopefully! Is it possible to show the numbers without the decimal points? Normally financial statements are presented as whole numbers.

Comment: Adjusted the code for group minimums to `\newcommand{\acount}[1]% #1 = number
{\IfBeginWith{#1}{-}{\StrBehind{#1}{-}[\temp](\num[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits = 4]{\temp}\rlap{)}}%
 {\num[group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits = 4]{#1}}}` so I could show commas in figures less than 10000.